# MongoDB 4.4: Compare particular date with an interval of other date

Tags: mongodb

Basically what I want to do is to compare that the difference between 2 date is less than 1 year, i.e. `scheduled_end < scheduled_start + 1 year`

I'm trying to use the following expression, but it does not seem valid:

```
scheduled_end: { 
  $lt: { 
    $add: [scheduled_start, 365*24*60*60000 ] 
  } 
}
```

How to fix it?

I'm using MongoDB 4.4, so `$dateAdd` is not available in this version.

Comment: You can directly use the calculated amount of milliseconds(i.e. 31536000000)

Comment: My syntax above is not correct... it's not about 365*24*60*60000 = 31536000000...

Comment: try again with `$expr` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZuuGqPuYMfy)

Comment: what if scheduled_end and scheduled_start is actually stored in string instead of a date object ?

Comment: try with [`$toLong`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/). A better alternative would be refactoring the schema to store them in proper date objects.